# check existense of div with id and insert some html code

Tags: dynamic, conditional-statements, jwplayer

How can I insert something just below a certain div?

I have a jwplayer on my page which usually have an id of jwplayer-1 being inserted by jwplayer plugin for wordpress.

What I want to be able to do is to insert a div just below that if it exist.

So for example, if my page has a player, somewhere on the page there will be

```
<div id="jwplayer-1>Player will appear here</div>
```

What I want to be able to do is to check if that line exist, if it does, insert another div so the code will be like this.

```
<div id="jwplayer-1>Player will appear here</div>
<div id="viewcount">Total Views: <?php showviews()?></div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
$('<div id="viewcount">Total Views: X</div>').insertAfter($('#jwplayer-1'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery's append method if you were to put your div within another div as such:

html:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="jwplayer-1>Player will appear here</div>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
$('.container').append('<div id="viewcount">Total Views: <?php showviews()?></div>');
```

sources:

http://api.jquery.com/append/